# normal distribution unknown notation

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, normal-distribution

I just stumbled upon some notation that I don't understand, a variable is defined as having a distribution of the following form:

$\mathcal{N}(a | b, c)$

What's what here? Pretty sure $c$ is the covariance, but what does the rest mean? Could it be an error?

In my particular case, it's even weirder, the distribution is actually:

$\mathcal{N}(a | \mathbf{0}, c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $c$ represents the covariance. In your case, $b$ represents the mean. In short, we have:

$$
\mathcal{N}(a|b,c)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c}} \exp \left\{ -\frac{(a-b)^2}{2c} \right\},
$$

or, in case $b$ represents a vector and $c$ represents a covariance matrix, we have:

$$
\mathcal{N}(a|b,c)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi |c|}} \exp \left\{ -(a-b)^Tc^{-1}(a-b) \right\},
$$

where $|c|$ represents the determinant of the covariance matrix.

Sometimes, the $a$ is omitted, such that the normal distribution is written as $\mathcal{N}(b,c)$, see, e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: Ok so $a$ is the name of the variable for which the distribution applies, got it. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!